# How can code return an array of characters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return, function-call

I have troubles getting this operation done. I actually want to create a function that returns a simple word from a scanf command, to get it called into main code. I know that functions cant return arrays properly, but II have seen lots of tutorial and don't understand it yet. For university purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

int function() {
  char word[100];
  scanf("%s", &word);
  return word;
}

int main() {
  char word2[100] = function();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `int function()` , the return value of this function is `int` but you want to get the string, so use `char * function()` instead.

And, `scanf("%s",&word);` do not use `&` for array of character.

The example for your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * function () {
    char * word = malloc(sizeof(64));
    if (!word)
       return NULL;
    scanf("%s",word);
    return word;
}
int main () {
    char * word2 = function();
    printf("%s\n", word2);
    free(word2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to remember to free your memory to prevent memory leaks and from running out of memory

Comment: Consider avoiding `scanf("%s",word);` as it is like [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Suggest `scanf("%63s",word);`

Answer (score 2):

So, the main problem is that functions cannot return array types, and you cannot copy the contents of one array to another using the `=` operator.  Arrays in C are different from other types.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type “N-element array of `T`” is converted (“decays”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`” and the *value* of the expression is the address of the first element.  So when you write

```
return word;
```

it’s being interpreted as

```
return &word[0];  // return char *
```

Since `word` is local to function, it *ceases to exist* when `function` exits, so you wind up returning an *invalid* pointer.

There are three ways around this:

**Declare `word` as `static`:**

```
char *function( void )
{
  static char word[100];

  scanf( "%s", word ); // no & operator here
  return word; // return char *
}
```

Declaring the array as `static` means it exists over the lifetime of the program, not just that function.  This works, but it limits the function’s utility, and is not recommended.

**Allocate the array dynamically:**

```
char *function( void )
{
  char *word = malloc( sizeof *word * 100 );

  scanf( "%s", word ); // again, no & operator
  return word;
}
```

This is better than making the array `static`, but now you have to make sure you `free` the array when you are finished with it.

**Pass the destination array as an argument to the function:**

```
void function( char *word, size_t size )
{
  scanf( "%s", word );
  return word;
}
```

This is my preferred method, but in this particular case you might as well just call `scanf` directly.

So that covers the function side, let’s tackle the caller side.

The only valid *initializers* for an array declaration are either a brace-enclosed sequence of values:

```
 char word[100] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

or, in the case of character arrays, a quoted string:

```
 char word[100] = "Hello";
```

You cannot initialize an array in a declaration with the result of a function, because a function cannot return array types.

To copy the contents of one array to another, you need to use either `strcpy` (for strings, which are arrays of `char` with a terminating `0`) or `memcpy` (for all other array types), and you can’t do that in a declaration.

If all you need to do is read a word into the array, just bypass `function` and call `scanf` directly:

```
int main( void )
{
  char word[100];

  scanf( “%s”, word );
  // do stuff with word
}
```